# Python_MySQL: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, mysql

When running the following code python code I get the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import random
import pymysql
import re

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd ='mypass', 
db='mysql',charset='utf8')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('USE scraping')

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

def store(title, content):

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pages")

     sql = """CREATE TABLE pages (id BIGINT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(200)
        , content VARCHAR(10000), created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(id))"""
cur.execute(sql)

cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pages (title, content) VALUES ("%s", "%s")""", (title, content))
cur.connection.commit()

def getLinks(articleUrl):
     html = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org'+articleUrl)
     bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
     title = bs.find('h1').get_text()
     content = bs.find('div', {'id':'mw-content-text'}).find('p').get_text
     store(title, content)
     #return bs.find('div',{'id':'bodyContent'}).findAll('a',href=re.compile('^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$'))

links = getLinks('/wiki/Kevin_Bacon')
#print(links)
```

I get the following error message:

```
  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

From what I can tell the failure point seems to be at this point in the code:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pages (title, content) VALUES ("%s", "%s")""", (title, content))
```

I've tried trouble shooting the issue by looking at the following:

```
- File "C:\Users\mypath\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 118, in escape_unicode
return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)

- File "C:\Users\mypath\PycharmProjects\Scraper\venv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
return value.translate(_escape_table)
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add parentheses in `get_text` function call, should be:

```
content = bs.find('div', {'id':'mw-content-text'}).find('p').get_text()
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help!